# Number of words per sentence

Tags: python, numpy

I am reading a text file in Python 2.7 and what I am trying to do is to fill out the count of words in each sentence of a text file in to 1D array. Here is what I have:

```
f = open(file_txt, 'r')

sen_prog = []

for line in f:
    sents = line.split('.')
    sen_prog.append(sents)

sen_p = []

for a in sen_prog:
    for b in a:
        sen_p.append(b)

sen_p = numpy.array(sen_p)
sen_p = sen_p[sen_p!='-']

sen_d = []


for c in sen_p:
    sen_d.append([len(x.split()) for x in sen_p])

sen_d = numpy.array(sen_d)
sen_d = numpy.ravel(sen_d)

print sen_prog, sen_d
```

The problem is that it is the array is created, but it gives out the wrong sentence count. My text file has 55 sentences (with each sentence separated by a full stop '.'), but it is giving out wrong figures...need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading in the file line by line. Assuming the file is like so, with a sentence spanning multiple lines, you may get a wrong count.

```
This is line 1. This 
is line 2. This is 
line 3.
```

sen_prog will have the value:

```
[ "This is line 1", "This", "is line 2", "This is", "line 3", ""]
```

This is perhaps not what you are looking for.

You may want to do:

```
sen_prog = " ".join(f.readlines()).split(".")
```

So that sen_prog is

```
[ "This is line 1", "This is line 2", "This is line 3", ""]
```

for the above input.

Comment: but I am splitting each sentence by the '.' ..yes, this is the sort of stuff I am getting in the resulting array..is there a more sensible way of approaching this (other than what I have)?

Comment: @khan as sandesh already said, you're not splitting sentences by '.', you're splitting lines.

Answer (score 1):

This makes a list with sentence length.

```
with open('path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    l = [len(x.split()) for x in f.read().split('.')]
```

Comment: @khan This will indeed work great for smaller files.  Depending on your input size, you may not want to read the whole file in one go, although, based on your algorithm you're doing that anyway...

Answer (score 0):

This should do it and will also account for multiple sentences on a single line:

```
sen_prog = []
sentence = ''

for line in f:
    parts = line.split('.')
    if len(parts) > 1:
        sentence += parts[0]
        sen_prog.append(sentence)
        if len(parts) > 2:
            sen_prog.append(parts[1:-1])
        sentence = parts[-1]
```